# Using EasyBind with subclass of NumberProperty

Tags: java, javafx-8, easybind

Before introducing EasyBind -

```
DoubleBinding contentHeight = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> getHeight() - getInsets().getTop() - getInsets().getBottom(),
    heightProperty(), insetsProperty());
```

After introducing EasyBind -

```
Binding<Double> contentHeight = EasyBind.combine(
    heightProperty(), insetsProperty(),
    (h, i) -> h.doubleValue() - i.getTop() - i.getBottom());
```

I'm somewhat uncomfortable regarding `doubleValue()` part. Every time I `combine` some subclass of `NumberProperty`, EasyBind passes `Number` instead of i.e. `Double`, `Integer`, ...

Is there some way to avoid `doubleValue()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not EasyBind that's causing the need for you to call `doubleValue()` - it's a consequence of the JavaFX API.

`EasyBind.combine()` has a parameter list `(ObservableValue<A>, ObservableValue<B>, BiFunction<A,B,R>)`, and returns a `Binding<R>`. For the first parameter you're passing in a `DoubleProperty`. The issue is that `DoubleProperty` (somewhat counter-intuitively) implements `ObservableValue<Number>`, not `ObservableValue<Double>`. The `combine` method invokes your BiFunction on the result of calling `getValue()` on the first two parameters: i.e. it calls `getValue()` on your `DoubleProperty`, which returns a `Number`, not a `Double`. Thus your `BiFunction` has to be a `BiFunction<Number, Insets, Double>` (mapping a `Number` and `Insets` to a `Double`).

You could consider implementing your `heightProperty` as a `ObjectProperty<Double>`, which would allow you to omit the call to `doubleValue()`; but it might make other parts of your application harder to code (specifically if you have other bindings to the height). I'm not sure I would consider the need to call `doubleValue()` a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I just felt calling `doubleValue()` is somewhat redundant, but fine. Implementing `heightProperty` as `ObjectProperty<Double>` would not be suitable, as it was from `javafx.scene.layout.Pane`.